# Continuity of a stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Exercise 3.11 in Oksendal's book "SDEs: an introduction with applications".

Let $W_t$ be a stochastic process satisfying

1. ${W_t}$ is stationary;
2. $t_1\not=t_2\implies W_{t_1}$ and $W_{t_2}$ are independent;
3. $E[W_t]=0$ $\forall t$.

**How to prove that $W_t$ cannot have continuous paths by considering $E[(W^{(N)}_t-W^{(N)}_s)^2]$ where
$W^{(N)}_t=(-N)\vee(N\wedge W_t)$?**

I am not sure where even where to start? We clearly have that $|W^{(N)}_t|\le N$ so maybe I should use bounded convergence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the paths are continuous then, for fixed $t$, you have $(W_s^{(N)} -W_t^{(N)})^2 \to 0$ when $s\to t$, and, by dominated convergence, the expectation goes to zero when $s\to t$, for every fixed $N$. On the other hand, $ E((W_s^{(N)} -W_t^{(N)})^2)= Var(W_s^{(N)}) +Var(W_t^{(N)}) \ge Var(W_t^{(N)})$, which, if $W_t$ is not degenerate, is bounded from zero when $N$ is large enough. So, if the paths are continuous and condition 2) holds, then every $W_t$ is degenerate. Then condition 3) implies that $W_t=0$ almost surely, for every $t$ (which indeed satisfies all the conditions). Condition 1) is superfetatory.

Comment: ... is that $Var(W_t)>0$.

Comment: How do you get $E[(W_s^{(N)} - W_t^{(N)})^2] = Var(W_s^{(N)} + Var(W_t^{(N)}$?

Comment: $W_s^{(N)}$ and $W_t^{(N)}$ are independent and have the same expectation.

Comment: Thanks for your question which shows that I did indeed use the stationarity condition 1).

Comment: @Galois1763 For zero-mean random variables, $\mathop{E}[X^{2}]=\mathop{Var}(X)$.  if $X$ and $Y$ are zero-mean and independent random variables, then $\mathop{E}[X-Y]=0$ and $\mathop{E}[(X-Y)^{2}]=\mathop{Var}(X-Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks! I completely forgot about the stationarity assumption.

Comment: @Jochen Just got a follow-up question: The above works, if we can guarantee stationarity of the $W_t^{(N)}$. But is this true, since we only assume $W_t$ to be stationary?

Comment: Statinarity implies that $W_t$ and $W_s$ have the same distribution hence so do $f(W_t)$ and $f(W_s)$ for all measurable functions $f$. Apply this to $f(x)=-N \vee (N\wedge x)$.