# Non existence of such stochastic process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

My question is concerned with the non-existence of a stochastic process satisfying certain properties. The exact same question was asked here:
[Continuity of a stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419449/continuity-of-a-stochastic-process)

In the answer it is stated that we have:
$$E[(W_t^{(N)} - W_s^{(N)})^2] = Var[W_t^{(N)}] + Var[W_s^{(N)}]  $$

For me it is not obvious why the equality holds, i.e. how we can get this from the properties that the stochastic process should satisfy.

Some help is really appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Continuity of a stochastic process](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419449/continuity-of-a-stochastic-process)

Comment: @d.k.o. I would be happy with this, if $E[W_t^{(N)}] = 0$, but we make the zero mean assumption for $W_t$. This causes my confusion. Maybe I am mixing up things, but the above equation is not obvious for me...

Comment: @BrianBorchers My question is concerned with the answer given in the problem you are referring to.

Comment: If you're having trouble understanding some detail of the accepted answer to the previous question, you can add a comment to that answer asking for clarification.